# How to display dialog below the action bar?

Tags: android

I want to display dialog below the action bar. But dialog display in full screen. That is dialog covers the action bar place too. So i couldn't do any action in action bar. how to over come this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style name="PopupTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateAlwaysHidden</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>.



private void showAsPopup(SherlockActivity activity) {
    //To show activity as dialog and dim the background, you need to declare android:theme="@style/PopupTheme" on for the chosen activity on the manifest
    //activity.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR); // NO NEED to call this line.
    activity.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    LayoutParams params = activity.getWindow().getAttributes(); 
    params.alpha = 1.0f;
    params.dimAmount = 0.5f;
    activity.getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params); 

    // This sets the window size, while working around the IllegalStateException thrown by ActionBarView
    activity.getWindow().setLayout(width,height);
}
```

Comment: What about adding explanations?